# Keep indented code but remove white space

Tags: powershell

Consider this simple code:

```
[String]$foo = "
    12CE8F-1A7F-42C8-CA99E
    14BA9A-2B2D-4A24-1498C
    foo
    bar"

Set-Content -Value $foo -Path "C:\Test\File.txt"
```

This inserts the string, separated line-by-line but with unwanted white space.

Is there a way to keep the indentation (for code readability) when declaring `$foo`, but remove unwanted white space in `File.txt`?

Comment: `ForEach ($Line in $foo) { Add-Content $Line.Trim() 'C:\Test\File.txt'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Remove All Leading Spaces

With your simple text example the easiest way would be to have a trailing regex statement that removed *all* leading spaces from the text.

```
[String]$foo = "
    12CE8F-1A7F-42C8-CA99E
    14BA9A-2B2D-4A24-1498C
    foo
    bar" -replace "(?m)^\s+"
```

`(?m)` : Causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of **each line** (not only begin/end of string). This is required since this is not a string array but a single multiline string.

#### Remove Certain amount of leading space

If you have indentation inside the string that you need to preserve then using something to remove that many spaces would work. This starts to fall apart if you are using tabs to indent so you could work on X number of tabs then or have leading newlines etc.

```
[String]$foo = "
    12CE8F-1A7F-42C8-CA99E
    14BA9A-2B2D-4A24-1498C
    foo
    bar" -replace "(?m)^\s{4}"
```

Is not perfect since there is that first newline there. If that was a concern putting a `.Trim()` would clean that up easy.

### Remove All Leading Spaces Until Character

The caveat of the first solution is that all your lines will have all leading spaces removed. You could also assign a control character that we act as the true start of the line

```
[String]$foo = "
    !12CE8F-1A7F-42C8-CA99E
    !   14BA9A-2B2D-4A24-1498C
    !   foo
    !bar".Trim() -replace "(?m)^\s*!"
```

Remove zero and all spaces at the start of each line until the `!`. We use `.Trim()` in this example to deal with that leading space.

**Note**: about `^\s+"` and Variants

You see the above solution rely on checking for all whitespace. If you have blank lines interspersed they play with the result. In that case you can always try `^ +"` to remove just literal spaces or `^[`t]+"` for spaces and tabs. Point is be consistent in what solution you choose and tailor your cleanup method to suit.

### StringBuilder

There are other options but then the code starts to get heavier. Manual string concatenation or using something like StringBuilder. These options are more useful for longer strings or string you are making as you go along.

```
$foo = New-Object -TypeName "System.Text.StringBuilder"
$foo.Append("12CE8F-1A7F-42C8-CA99E") | Out-Null 
    $foo.AppendLine("14BA9A-2B2D-4A24-1498C")  | Out-Null
        $foo.AppendLine("foo")  | Out-Null
    $foo.AppendLine("bar")  | Out-Null
    $foo.ToString()
```

and

```
$foo = ""
    $foo += "`n12CE8F-1A7F-42C8-CA99E"
    $foo += "`n14BA9A-2B2D-4A24-1498C"
$foo
```

and

```
$foo = "12CE8F-1A7F-42C8-CA99E`r`n" +
    "14BA9A-2B2D-4A24-1498C`r`n" +
    "bar"
```

Comment: The `[String]` class has a `.Trim()` method that removes leading/trailing whitespace.  It'd be easier to use that than re-invent the wheel with regex

Comment: Its a single string though. `Trim()` wont work here.

Comment: It will if you loop.  What does the `(?m)` mean?

Comment: You cant loop a single string. Just a string array. (?m) is for multiline mode so ^ matches the start of the line not just the start of the string.

Comment: Fancy.  I didn't know you could do that with PS regex.  His case is a little strange why he would store a multi-line string with spaces in them.  `ForEach ($Line in ($foo -split "`n"))`

Comment: He is doing it so that it looks good in the code. Else it can look horrible along side other indented code.

Comment: He can utilize string arrays or here-strings in that case.

Comment: here-strings would have the same issue. And if you are going to split the string its a trade off which solution is preferred since they both use regex. Mine does not need a  loop just a small collection of characters after the string.